# While loop with boolean not terminating

Tags: java, string, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am writing a program to remove consecutive duplicate characters in a String using below program:

```
static void main(String[] args){

String s = "abcdeedcbfgf";
removeConsecutiveDuplicate(s);

}

    static void removeConsecutiveDuplicate(String s) {
        String tmp = "";
        boolean isEligible = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i + 1)) {
                tmp = s.substring(0, i) + s.substring((i + 2), s.length());
                System.out.println(tmp);
                s = tmp;
                isEligible = true;
                break;
            } 
        }

        System.out.println("s is:" + s);
        while ( isEligible)
            removeConsecutiveDuplicate(s);
    }
```

The output should be: **afgf** when there are no consecutive characters and it should stop as I am using flag in while. But the flag is getting true value.

I don't know how is it doing it?

Can somebody help me understand where I am doing something wrong?

Comment: This is because `isEligible` never changes value in the frame that it is first declared.  How long will this run? because it seems to me you would end up running out of heap really fast

Comment: i.e. every time you call `removeConsecutiveDuplicate()` you are generating a new scope and a new value for `isEligible`.  This new value will **NOT** transfer back, nor is it visible to your initial while loop

Comment: The string `s` in `main()` will remain the same after the call (when you get it to do as desired and return afterwards). I think you would want the method to return the altered `s` to the caller.

Comment: @CraigR8806 - But the `while` loop, such that it is, is **inside** the function?

Comment: @CraigR8806: Even if I remove the flag from for loop and put it as method parameter, it is going in infinite loop..

Comment: Look at @Bohemian 's answer.  He will get you on the right track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to *return* the new String from your method:

```
static String removeConsecutiveDuplicate(String s) {
    // existing code, except...
    return tmp;
}
```

Then in the calling method, check if it *changed*:

```
String s = "abcdeedcbfgf";

while (true) {
    String next = removeConsecutiveDuplicate(s);
    if (next.equals(s))
        break;
    s = next;
}
```

Remove the variable and concept of `isEligible` entirely.

---

Also, you don't need to specify the second parameter to `substring()`, because if omitted "to end of String" is implied, that is:

```
s.substring(i, s.length())
```

Is identical to

```
s.substring(i);
```

Comment: s.substring(i, s.length) will remove the unidentical charcaters..tried below code:        <pre> <code>                                                                             String removeConsecutiveDuplicate(String s){
 String tmp = "";
 
 for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
  if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i + 1)) {
   tmp = s.substring(i, s.length());
   System.out.println("tmp is:"+tmp);
   break;
  } 
 }


 return tmp; 
} </code></pre>
It does not work..

Comment: Oh, you still need `s.substring(0, i)`. You may do `s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i + 2)`, leaving out the second argument to the *second* call to `substring()`.

Comment: @Bohemian: Thanks for the solution. It really helped. Can you also explain why can't I use "while loop" the way I used?? And the way you have used is working..Infact the while loop that you have used must end up being an endless loop.

Comment: @YogeshMalhotra The while loop exits when "the string didn't change", which is the intention of your original code.

Answer (score 1):

While loop is while(true) . You are never making it false . 
once iseligible is true , You are running into a infinite loop . 
change while to if .
while(iseligible) => if(iseligible) .

Comment: No, I don’t think so. The asker has the condition`i < s.length() - 1`, so `i + 1` will equal `s.length() - 1` at most. No issue here.

Comment: oops!! my bad . Changed the answer Now . Thank you @Ole V.V.

Comment: It worked when I changed while to IF. But I am unable to understand how? Whether it is while or If, when I am making a recursion call, isEligible is changing to false. Can you help me out here?

Comment: It’s because each invocation of your recursive method has its own `isEligible` variable. The caller doesn’t see the change in the called method. Go read your chapter on recursion once again.

Comment: @OleV.V.: I know that there was some problem with the while loop. But I am putting condition of flag, so when it is false, why would it enter again? While loop Definition saysThat " it calls itself at the end" has no stack to crawl back up when it's done. It's last iteration sets what state will be as it ends.